# Application to scan and recommend Services and Startup apps you can safely disable

Tags: windows-10

I am looking for a windows 10 application that can scan the services and startup apps and then recommend things to disable. I am currently using "msconfig" to do this manually but there are so many services and I spend a lot of time googling them to find out what they do or what some process that is booting up dose.

I would think that there must be an app that is trustworthy that can source this same information and make recommendations for services to switch off and startup apps we do not need.

Dose anyone know any?

Comment: I know `Hijackthis` which scans your PC for possible threats. You can generate a log file and let the website analyze it for you. Tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/ analyze website: https://www.hijackthis.de/ The report looks like this: http://www.pchell.com/images/hijackthisonline.gif

Comment: In late 2010 Soluto [http://lifehacker.com/5561303/soluto-is-an-awesome-tool-to-speed-up-your-system-boot-fix-system-slowdowns] used to do exactly what you want. But now they are a tech support company and I don't know where you can find the latest release of the app or if it works with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a few that give recommendations, such as WinPatrol, but they just make the process at best slightly easier.

Unfortunately I don't think the application you're looking for exists. Mainly because what is unnecessary on my system may be vital on yours. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I was thinking an app would be around that would automatically list the processes and draw form one of those databases on the net google finds when looking up what processes do. Guess not.